# Predicting probability of order arriving on or before customer Requested Delivery Date(RDD)

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling

I have a historical data of orders from different customers of my company and delivery details. I wanted to develop a model which predicts the probability of customers order getting delivered before or on the "Requested Delivery Date".

In my data-set, i've details about 
customer
delivery location
product
delivery type
product classification (Can be exported or not) etc.

I was not able to start this model as I am not sure how to tackle this problem. It would be of great help, if you could suggest some reading material on the same or few link directing the same.

Comment: I have two options in mind: Use a *regression model* to predict number of days for product to arrive. Or use a *classification model* to predict whether or not a delivery while arrive before a given time. Look those terms up and start learning :)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing here is to model your problem as time series, as you know, each example consists of one customer that has many orders over time. see [Predicting Clinical Events via Recurrent Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v56/Choi16.html)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your dataset is going to need some work before you can start applying a model to it, for example you will have to translate customer location into something more usable, like distance from depot, or Urban/Suburb/Country labels perhaps?

[Andrew Ng's Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) is a popular starting point, many beginners seem to find it useful. You'll get a good understanding of machine learning algorithms and how to arrange your data to get the best out of the models.

Good luck!